# Exibição de div apenas após o carregamento total da mesma (Preloader)

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Olá, pessoal!

Não sei nada de javascript, mas gostaria de alterar esse código js para que o conteúdo de uma determinada div só apareça após o carregamento da mesma **e não após o carregamento da página toda**.

Gostaria que a div "**.preloader**" seja exibida enquanto a div "**.conteudo**" é carregada. Com o carregamento completo, a div ".preloader" desaparece e a div ".conteudo" é exibida, enquanto o navegador continua a carregar os scripts que estão antes do fechamento do "**body**".

Não quero usar jQuery no head, pra que eu possa otimizar o tempo de carregamento do conteúdo e ele só seja carregado após a exibição da página.

Em outras palavras, é um preloader de uma div e não da página inteira.

Gostaria também que a div "**.preloader**" mostrasse uma barra de progresso baseado no carregamento da div "**.conteudo**" apenas com Javascript e CSS.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="preloader"></div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <header></header>
    <main>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
  <script src="jquery"></script>
  <script src="config"></script>
  <script src="wow"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao utilizar '$' deve garantir que sua página ou projeto esteja fazendo o uso do arquivo jQuery local ou online. No Seu caso procure adicionar 
no script o source online do jQuery utilizando: src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"

> > https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp